# 2 fingers touches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

in my app i used touchesBegan , touchesMoved and touchesEnd but i faced a big problem if the user drag 2 fingers **just one finger handle the drag**. how can i fix this bug ?

Answer (score 0):

```
myView.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: hi... do you solved this problem?? i face the same case, can you share your answer to me??